# Convexity of a functional defined on the solution of an ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, convex-analysis

Consider the following ODE
$$ \dot x(t) = f(x(t),u(t)), t \in [0,T]. $$
where $f$ is smooth, $u(t) \in \mathbb R$ is measurable, and $x(t)=[x_1(t),..,x_n(t)]^T \in \mathbb R^n$, with an initial condition $x(0)$

I am interested in the functional:
$$\varphi: u \mapsto \int_0^T x_n(t) .$$

Are there some results that can be used to prove that $\varphi$ is convex?

Comment: You need an initial condition.  But I see no reason to think $\phi$ is convex.

Comment: I added an initial condition, sorry forgot that.
yes, in general, it does not need to be convex. but I am looking for general results to decide if \varphi is convex for a given f